# ¿Cómo agrego elementos aleatorios en una lista vacía de otra con elementos y un número determinado de elementos a repetir?

Tags: python, lista

Llevo días tratando de resolver ¿Cómo agregar 12 elementos de forma aleatoria de la lista lista_numeros a la lista lista_nueva?, pero con un máximo de *4 elementos* repetidos de cada elemento de la *lista_numeros*. Creo que se empezaría como estoy mostrando en una de mis lineas mas explicitamente en `for x in range(12)`, pero no comprendo el cómo seguir la verdad que he intentado de mil maneras, con otro *for* dentro, con un *while* dentro, ya no sé qué hacer

### Anexo codigo:

```
import random

lista_numeros = [1, 2, 3]
lista_nueva = []
    
for x in range(12):
    aleatorio = random.randint(0, len( lista_numeros) - 1)
    lista_nueva.append(lista_numeros[aleatorio])
```

### Por ejemplo:

```
lista_nueva = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Necesariamente no tendria porque estar ordenados solo busco que haya un máximo de 4 elementos repetidos, es lo que estoy tratando de hacer y ya no me da el cerebro.

Ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Para este ejercicio necesitará usar el método `random.choice()` este método devuelve un elemento seleccionado aleatoriamente de una lista el cual será de gran ayuda para elegir los elementos de la variable `lista_numeros`. A continuación anexo el código y mas adelante explicaré como funciona:

```
import random
lista_numeros= [1,2,3,4,1,23,21,4,1,3,4,5,5,6,6]
lista_nueva= []
while len(lista_nueva) < 12:
  for i in range(12):
    numero= random.choice(lista_numeros)
    if lista_nueva.count(numero) < 4:
      lista_nueva.append(numero)
print(lista_nueva)
```

---

### ¿Como funciona?

Lo que haremos será evaluar mediante un ciclo `while` si la longitud de la `lista_nueva` < **12**, de ser así se repetirá el proceso de buscar aleatoriamente números y que estos no estén contenidos en la lista `lista_nueva` mas de *4 veces*.

### Resultado:

```
[21, 5, 23, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 23, 21, 1, 4]
```

Como puede notar obtenemos una lista con 12 números aleatoriamente y ninguno de ellos se repite mas de `4 veces`

### Nota adicional:

Este algoritmo funciona siempre y cuando su lista contenga como minimo *3 números* y éstos sean diferentes de no ser asíquedará en un bucle infinito, matemáticamente hablando se puede comprender mejor leyendo el concepto de [Combinaciones y Permutaciones](https://www.neurochispas.com/wiki/diferencia-entre-permutacion-y-combinacion/)

Dando solución a su problemática solo debe cambiar `lista_numeros` por los valores que otorgó al principio:

```
lista_numeros = [1,2,3]
```

Obteniendo como salida:

```
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Era lo que estaba buscando, Muchas gracias, Jred0n29

Comment: Buen día @Ulises Leonel Gonzalez si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [Lectura recomendada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Jred0n29 he vuelto a eliminar el ruido de tu post. Usar saludos como *buen día*, o *buenas tardes*, etc. se considera ruido innecesario, no aportan a la publicación. Toma en cuenta que no sólo te diriges al OP sino al resto de la comunidad, y no todos estamos en la misma zona horaria en la que tú estás. Entiendo el tema de la educación y el respeto, pero en el caso de esta comunidad, el saludo está implícito en la respuesta que de buen agrado has proporcionado. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras yo creo que poner saludos en una respuesta esta perfecto. No esta bueno ser un frio que no siquiera responde a un gracias... Es algo en que yo y el resto de la comunidad no coincidimos. Ademas, HeytalePazguato hace lo mismo y nadie le dice nada.

Comment: No he visto o editado nada de quien mencionas, pero si lo viera haría lo mismo. Les sugiero leer [Escribiendo la pregunta perfecta](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (que aplica también a las respuestas), sobre todo la sección titulada *Making a good impression*, que en uno de sus apartados dice: *There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and... These will often be edited out by other users, as they’re basically a distraction*. Para ello pueden usar los comentarios. Saludos

Comment: Si la cortesia es una distraccion, por que habria que ser corteses en el mundo real? Ademas, la ultima seccion... Que hacen juzgando una pregunta sin entrar a ella primero? Leyendo solo la parte de abajo que no aporta nada? Hay que hacer lo posible por no juzgar un libro por su portada. De hecho, literalmente trato de leer la contraportada de un libro antes de decir "no me interesa". @MauricioContreras

Comment: Supuestamente los comentarios "no son para socializar" (eso dice el centro de ayuda) asi que segun las normas, no deberia ni agradecer ni decir estas cosas (pienso eliminar estos comentarios cuando termine)

Comment: La conversación se torna interesante pido amablemente eliminar los comentario, y continuar en una sala de chat.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas hacer nada del otro mundo. El modulo random incluye la función
[sample](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/random.html#random.sample), que nos permitirá obtener una solución simple.
sample nos permite obtener una lista de longitud k con items elegidos al azar de un iterable sin que ningún item se repita (excepto si en el iterable se repite, por ejemplo si en el iterable está 1 dos veces, va a aparecer en el resultado de sample hasta 2 veces, no más).

El primer argumento de sample es una secuencia (como una lista) y k nos dice el largo que debe tener la muestra.

Los siguientes dos códigos fueron probados en Python 3.9.

#### Solución 1 (3.9 o superior)

Código usando el argumento counts, que según la documentación está disponible desde Python 3.9:

###### Código

```
import random

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

resultado = random.sample(lista, k=12, counts=[4]*len(lista))

print(resultado)
```

###### Produce

```
[4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
```

counts indica, para cada item de la secuencia respectivamente, cuantas veces como maximo puede repetirse en la muestra. Tomando prestado de la documentación: `sample(['red', 'blue'], counts=[4, 2], k=5)` es equivalente a `sample(['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'], k=5)`

Al hacer `[4] * len(lista)` estamos creando una lista con tantos 4 como items tiene la lista. Y como sabemos, cada 4 indica cuantas veces como maximo puede repetirse dicho item en la lista.

#### Solución 2 (sin usar el parametro count)

Pero quizá buscas una solución que tenga compatibilidad con versiones inferiores de Python. Para eso ofresco la siguiente solución:

###### Código

```
import random

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

para_pasar_a_sample = []

for item in lista:
    para_pasar_a_sample.extend([item]*4)

print("a pasar a sample:", para_pasar_a_sample)

resultado = random.sample(para_pasar_a_sample, k=12)

print("resultado", resultado)
```

###### Produce

```
a pasar a sample: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
resultado [5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 1]
```

Se basa en la documentación. La idea es crear una nueva lista donde cada elemento de la anterior se repita 4 veces seguidas. Por ejemplo obtener a partir de `[1, 2, 3]` a `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]` y eso pasarselo a sample.

Comment: Tan solo probar la primera solución me sirvió. Muchas gracias, DanteS

Comment: @UlisesLeonelGonzalez de nada Ulises c: Por cierto, estaría bueno que aceptaras la respuesta que más te sirvió. Lectura recomendada: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) nwn

Answer (score 1):

El método `count()` es tu salvación: antes de agregar el valor seleccionado, cuenta cuantas veces aparace en `lista_nueva`. Si ya tiene cuatro ocurrencias, entonces pasas a la siguiente iteración:

```
import random

lista_numeros = [1, 2, 3]
lista_nueva = []

while len(lista_nueva) < 12:
    aleatorio = random.randint(0, len( lista_numeros) - 1)
    valor = lista_numeros[aleatorio]
    if lista_nueva.count(valor) < 4:
        lista_nueva.append(valor)

print(lista_nueva)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si mal no estoy necesita una salida con 12 numeros y que cuando tu condicion es *False* deja de agregar un numero.

Comment: No funciona exactamente como es que lo quiero

Comment: @Jred0n29. Cierto. Arreglado